# Enumeration of labeld trees with at least 3 leafs Updated (one more question)

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

In the Question : all trees T such that $V=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$
Find : number of trees such that 2,4,6 leafs at least
No more conditions .\

Sol
I suspect ii'l have to use cayely for labeld trees
We know:n^n-2 trees
We start by stating that we recognize that if we take 2 4 6 \

to be leafs that leaves us with
4 verticies and we count how many trees with 4 verticies where 2 4 6 leafs
\
Next we take forth leaf , there is 5 ways to chose forth leaf
And 4 vertecies left
Than
To chose 2 leafs there is $5choose2$
... to choose 3 leafs and we get 2 verticies we done .

Than :
$4^5$+  $ 4 \times \ 3^5$ +$4\choose 2 $$ \times 2^5$

Is it the correct way,or the actual solution mybe ?

Some one knows? I cannot tell

Update :

$4^5$ is the currect answer beacuse beside 2 4 6 other leafs are included

**Update :
if the question was : such that  will be leafs at least one of 2,4,6
the solution will be 

$3\choose 1 $$6^5$ ?**

Comment: The answer is just $4^5$, none of the other terms. The fact that other vertices besides $2,4,6$ can be leaves is already accounted for in the $4^2$, the application of Cayley's formula to choose a tree with vertices $\{1,3,5,7\}$./

Comment: Thank you, i didnt think about it nor i could reach this answer and therefore thank you for this.